# $output displays incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, plugins, foreach

I got an issue where I run a foreach loop I want it to just display what's in the array() but when I output the loop it displays "arrayclient" instead of just client. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php 
            $data_array = array("client","task","brand");

            $output = '<div class="clientele">';

            foreach($data_array as $data) {
                $output .= '<section>';
                $output .= '<img src='. get_template_directory_uri()."/img/{$data}.png />";
                $output .= '<h2>'. $field = get_field_object($data);
                $output .= $field['label']. '</h2>';
                $output .= '<p>'. $field['value']. '</p>';
                $output .= '</section>';
            }
            $output .= '</div>';
            echo $output;
            ?>
```

the reasonsing with $field = get_field_object($) is because i'm using a plugin to make custom fields on a post and want those fields to display because "client","task", and "brand" are those field labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $output .= '<h2>'. $field = get_field_object($data);
            $output .= $field['label']. '</h2>';
```

Should be

```
  $field = get_field_object($data);
  $output .= '<h2>'.$field['label'].'</h2>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$field = get_field_object($data);
$output .= '<h2>'. $field;
```

instead of

```
$output .= '<h2>'. $field = get_field_object($data);
```

?

No clue what `get_field_object` does. It seems not to be a function that appears in the PHP reference. It would be helpful if you posted its' code.

Can you also provide the full output please?

Answer (score 0):

You should use rather:

```
$output .= '<h2>'. $field = get_field_object($data)[0];
```

Instead of:

```
$output .= '<h2>'. $field = get_field_object($data);
```

As with other custom fields WordPress allows to exist several field values with the same key, so you have to specify which one you wish to output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! I did try each and it seemed that the info that KutePHP gave seemed to work best. Here is my final code.

```
<?php 
            $data_array = array("client","task","brand");
            $output = '<div class="clientele">';

            foreach($data_array as $data) {
                $output .= '<section>';
                $output .= '<img src='. get_template_directory_uri()."/img/{$data}.png />";
                $field = get_field_object($data);
                $output .= '<h2>'.$field['label'].'</h2>';
                $output .= '<p>'.$field['value'].'</p>';
                $output .= '</section>';
            }
            $output .= '</div>';
            echo $output;
            ?>
```